# Consuming a Hapi JS API from a separate Vue JS Frontend. request.payload is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, hapi.js

I'm having my first steps on Hapi JS. My app connects with a SQL Server DB.

However, I'm tryng to send login data from Vue CLI JS frontend to Hapi JS Api, I'm using axios for this.  A Login is a "SELECT * FROM" query, so I put "get" in the axios function code.

[image]

This is the function that works but i can't send password by URL, it's not safe, with F12 you'll can see the user credentials for free encrypted or not.

[image]

And this is the Hapi JS route that receives the data. It works like this, but it's not worth for me doing this. I want my code work like this:

[image]

Axios function

[image]

Hapi JS route with "request.payload" instead "request.query"

But when I try this, there is an error in console that says: "Cannot destructure username from request.payload of undefined" and in fact a console.log of request.payload is undefined :C I really need help.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! I recommend you to use text instead of images to share code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem stems from your endpoint HTTP method. An HTTP GET request cannot have a payload. You should send it as a POST request instead.

On axios:

```js
axios.post(config.url, { username: parametros.username, password: parametros.password }).then(...)
```

On the hapi side you should set `method: 'POST'` in your route definition. That
way you should now have access to the `request.payload` property. You should also validate the payload that you receive from your client. Here is some documentation on it: https://hapi.dev/tutorials/validation/?lang=en_US.

Also on a side note, if you want to add a cookie to the response of the server you should set it using the Response Toolkit (the second parameter `h` in your handler):

```js
return h.response(someValue).state('auth-cookie', { NOM_USUARIO: account.NOM_USUARIO })
```

Here is some documentation to help you out:
https://hapi.dev/api/?v=20.1.0#-hstatename-value-options

Good luck and hapi coding.